# li:hover doesn't get triggered

Tags: html, css

I haven't done this in a long time and I looked it up aswell but when I hover over an li I expect its child UL to open up (display), but it isn't:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products&nbsp;<img src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/LIItemArrow.png" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li>Hi</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services&nbsp;<img src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/LIItemArrow.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop&nbsp;<img src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/LIItemArrow.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
ul li ul { display: none; }

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

According to the several articles I looked up, I believe that I'm doing this right, so why won't this work?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/y3Ltv/

Comment: Works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/pGaa9/

Comment: working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/zNU9C/

Comment: Yeah, it works for me in the Fiddle too. Just not on my blank webpage which only has that 1 menu with that one bit of css :-/

Comment: Any specific condition/browser etc? seems to work for all of us.

Comment: You may have to dig deeper as i doubt it very much that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add height: auto, so your code would become

```
ul li ul { display: none; }

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
   height: auto;
}
```

I had similar problems while I was creating menu.